# Mean Value Relation and Harmonic Functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian

I try to answer the following question:

> Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $h:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function satisfying
> $$R\int_{\partial B_R{\left(y\right)}}h\left(x\right)d\sigma=n\int_{B_R\left(y\right)}h\left(x\right)dx$$
> for all $B_R\left(y\right)\subset\subset \Omega$. Is $h$ is harmonic in $\Omega$?

My hunch is No. Here's my reason. Notice that the classical mean value formula on harmonic functions says the (area/volume) average of a harmonic function should be equal to the value at the center, to wit
$$ h\left(y\right)= \frac{1}{n\omega_nR^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_R\left(y\right)} h\left(x\right)d\sigma=\frac{1}{\omega_nR^{n}}\int_{B_R\left(y\right)}h\left(x\right)dx,$$
where $\omega_n$ indicates the volume of the unit $n$-ball, whenever $B_R\left(y\right)\subset\subset \Omega$ if $h:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic. Yet from the assumption, $h$ only satisfies the equation (divide $n\omega_n R^{n}$ on both sides of the given equation)
$$ \frac{1}{n\omega_nR^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_R\left(y\right)} h\left(x\right)d\sigma=\frac{1}{\omega_nR^{n}}\int_{B_R\left(y\right)}h\left(x\right)dx,$$
which $h\left(y\right)$ doesn't necessarily have to be equal to the average. Although we know that the mean value property implies harmonicity, the mean value property still requires **the average should be equal to the value at the center**. As such, it seems to be less likely for $h$ to be a harmonic function. However, I haven't find out any example to verify my guess, so I would like to ask if my guess is true or $h$ is really a harmonic function under the assumption.

For the record, by **the mean value property** in the last paragraph, I mean

> A continuous function $h:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ is said to have the mean value property if for each $y\in \Omega$, there exists a sequence of positive numbers $\left\{r_i\right\}$ with $r_i\to 0$ as $i\to \infty$ such that
> $$ h\left(y\right)=\frac{1}{n\omega_n{r_i}^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_{r_i}\left(y\right)} h\left(x\right)d\sigma$$ for all $r_i$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On one hand I agree with your hunch that at first it does not seem obvious that your second equation would imply $u$ has the mean value property. On the other hand, it seems as if this question is an exam/assignment question which made me think that actually $u$ would be harmonic. I believe that the answer is **yes $u$ is harmonic** and I came up with two proofs of this fact.

---

Proof 1: Let $$ \phi (\rho) = \int_{ B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d x .$$   By polar coordinates $$\phi'(\rho)=\frac{d}{d \rho}\int_{ B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d x = \int_{\partial B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d \sigma_x . $$ Since $$  \int_{\partial B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d \sigma_x =\frac n \rho \int_{ B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d x $$ we have that $$\phi'(\rho) = \frac n \rho \phi(\rho). $$ The general solution to this ODE is $$ \phi(\rho) = A \rho^n.$$ Then $$A = \lim_{\rho \to 0^+} \frac{\phi(\rho)}{\rho^n}=\lim_{\rho \to 0^+} \frac1{\rho^n}\int_{ B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d x =\omega_n h(y).$$ Thus, $\phi(\rho) = \omega_n u(y) \rho^n$ which we can rewrite as $$u(y) = \frac 1 {\omega_n \rho^n}\int_{ B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d x . $$ This means $h$ satisfies the mean value property so it is harmonic.

---

Proof 2: This one needs that $h$ is $C^2$ which you haven't assumed but I still thought it was worth sharing. (This was actually the first proof I came up with). It is well known (see for example Thm 1.1.1 & 1.1.2 in [Elliptic partial differential equations
from an elementary viewpoint by E. Valdinoci & S. Dipierro](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.07941.pdf)) that $$\frac1 {\rho^2} \bigg ( \frac 1 {n \omega_n \rho^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d \sigma_x -h(y) \bigg ) \to \frac 1 {2n} \Delta h(y)$$ and $$ \frac1 {\rho^2} \bigg ( \frac 1 { \omega_n \rho^n} \int_{ B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d x -h(y) \bigg ) \to \frac 1 {2(n+1)} \Delta h(y)$$ as $\rho \to 0^+$. As you stated, we know that $$\frac 1 {n \omega_n \rho^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d \sigma_x = \frac 1 { \omega_n \rho^n} \int_{ B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d x  .$$ It follows that $$\frac1 {\rho^2} \bigg ( \frac 1 {n \omega_n \rho^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d \sigma_x -h(y) \bigg ) = \frac1 {\rho^2} \bigg ( \frac 1 { \omega_n \rho^n} \int_{ B_\rho (y) }h(x) \, d x -h(y) \bigg ). $$ Sending $\rho \to 0^+$, we obtain $$\frac 1 {2n} \Delta h(y) =  \frac 1 {2(n+1)} \Delta h(y). $$ Hence, $\Delta h(y)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your fabulous answer! Yet, I just found that I had several typos in this post. In short, every single $u$ that appeared in the last edition has been replaced with $h$. I am really sorry that I misled you...

Comment: I just worked on your solution again and it works if $u$ is replaced with $h$!

Comment: Ah whoops I also have typos… whenever I wrote $u$ I also meant $h$